# Процессы, запущенные через библиотеку Python subprocess не могут обращаться к другим файлам

Tags: python, windows, файлы, файловая-система, subprocess

Запускаю на Windows (с правами Администратора), пытаюсь запустить исполняемый `.exe` через библиотеку `subprocess`:

```
>>> import subprocess

>>> subprocess.run(['C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\hashcat-6.2.1\\hashcat.exe', '--help'], shell=True)
hashcat (v6.2.1) starting...
CompletedProcess(args=['C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\hashcat-6.2.1\\hashcat.exe', '--help'], returncode=4294967295)

>>> subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\hashcat-6.2.1\\hashcat.exe', '--help'], shell=True)
hashcat (v6.2.1) starting...
./OpenCL/: No such file or directory
4294967295

>>> subprocess.getoutput(['C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\hashcat-6.2.1\\hashcat.exe', '--help'])
'hashcat (v6.2.1) starting...\n\n./OpenCL/: No such file or directory\n'
```

Как видно, процесс запускается с помощью `subprocess` (о чём говорит вывод `hashcat (v6.2.1) starting...`), но выдаёт ошибку каждый раз когда обращается к другим файлам/директориям.

Это связано с ограничениями/ошибками исполнительный среды Python (что-то вроде песочницы), или же проблема в ограничениях Windows? В любом из этих случаев, как их устранить?

P. S. Я уже пытался искать информацию по поводу этой проблемы, но поиск ничего не дал по причине того, что большинство материалов по этой теме связано с Linux, а не Windows.

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Так а вы уверены, что файл существует и путь к нему верен?

Comment: @КириллМалышев да, точно. Если запускать прямиком из cmd.exe, то эта папка находится процессом.

Comment: Путь до файла абсолютный или относительный?

Comment: @КириллМалышев пробовал и то и то.

Comment: Файлы на одном диске?

Comment: @КириллМалышев да.

Comment: Попробуйте такую команду запускать: `cd C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\hashcat-6.2.1 && ./hashcat.exe`

Comment: https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/1539